# Want to alter multiple pivot result

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am using two pivot operators with union all in my query and I am getting data which I wanted 
but I am getting the data from second pivot as new rows but I want these values to come as new  columns in the table. I am getting data like this:

```
Name    Ep  ER  FT  SQ       
Amir    2   9   3   2         
muzamil NULL    5   NULL     
roof    2   9   3   7        
Amir    0   9   3   1
muzamil NULL    5   NULL     
roof    2   7   3   7
```

First three rows are output of first pivot and last three rows are output of second pivot.But I want values in last three rows come as new columns to the first three rows.

I want data to be output like this:

```
Name    Ep  ER  FT  SQ          JB  CQ   LQ   YC
Amir    2   9   3   2            0   9   3   1
muzamil NULL    5   NULL        NULL 5  NULL NULL
roof    2   9   3   7             2  7   3    7
```

with JB  CQ   LQ   YC as new columns from last three  rows my pivot query is like this:

```
Declare @S  nvarchar(1024)
 Declare @Q nvarchar(Max)
set @S=''
Select   @S=@S+a.[Column] +',' from
(SELECT  distinct   ISNULL( dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode,'NoColumnName') as [Column] FROM         dbo.tbAttendance INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbAttendanceMaster ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSubjects ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID
                      ) as a

set @S=LEFT(@S,LEN(@S)-1)
 print @S
set @Q='select Name,'+@S+' from (SELECT  distinct tbStudent.Name,   dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode, dbo.fnTotalDays(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID, 
dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Total 

FROM         dbo.tbAttendance INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbAttendanceMaster ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSubjects ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID ) sq
                      pivot(sum(Total)   for SubCode IN('+@S+') ) as pt
 union all
'
set @Q=@Q+'select Name,'+@S+' from (SELECT  distinct tbStudent.Name,   dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode, dbo.fnNoOfDays(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID, dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Present

FROM         dbo.tbAttendance INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbAttendanceMaster ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSubjects ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID ) sq2
                      pivot(sum(Present)   for SubCode IN('+@S+') ) as pt2

'
 Execute sp_Executesql @Q
print @Q
```

Comment: are columns JB CQ LQ YC included in @S var? if not pivot will never show them.

Comment: no they are not included but I can include them but real problem is with union all